# How does getLegendGraphic, from GeoServer, handle attribute-based styles?

Tags: geoserver, sld, select-by-attribute, getlegendgraphic

I have a layer with a `color` attribute and I write an SLD with a fill color like this:

```
<sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
    <sld:Fill>
        <sld:CssParameter name="fill">
            <ogc:PropertyName>color</ogc:PropertyName>
        </sld:CssParameter>
    </sld:Fill>
</sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
```

Each geometry will have its own fill color, based on the value of its color attribute.

However, the legend does not reflect that.

Does GeoServer have a way to generate a good legend for this kind of SLD body, where we have attribute-based styles?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131386/getlegendgraphic-request-string-is-too-long